# Can't understand some things with making a bootstrap card , I'm a rookie

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to do this card. I've done all, but my row with Date and time sucks. Please, help me to do it correctly. The first image shows how it must be, the second is mine. I don't know how to do: 1)a proper space between input date and input time. 2)How to make this card to be responsive so on the extrasmall screens it would take all 12 col. 3)why my radios are grey ? in the example they are white

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="date" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"> <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">

                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="input-group-addon"> <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
            </div>
            </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: ahhh my images didn't get into question

Comment: This is what I did
http://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/8/5/227e8759421480279e32a0989154b825-full.png
http://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/8/5/ae0b91d11b80008f9684d3f4e4e2c710-full.png
This is how it must be

Comment: Please edit your question to include the links to the pictures there instead of in comments. Also, add the CSS you have so far into your question as a code block. It'd be extra good if you could turn your code into a stack snippet that could be run to immediately see the result of your code as shown in image 1. (Use the icon of a piece of paper with brackets on it to make a stack snippet.)

Comment: If you need help, you need to share what you already did, you just add a piece of code that is only for "Date and Time" and two images which are useless for people here. update your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535847/cant-make-a-bootstrap-card

Answer (score 0):

I solved to you the 3 problems, check the code, the last style I put it inline but you can use the class of bootstrap and put what you want of props and add (!important)  to take your style

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="date" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>

          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
             <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white"> <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
                 </div>   
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
             <div class="input-group">
                 <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: white"> <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
                     </div>   
            </div>       

    </div>
```